# Error: Expression must have class type for size()

Tags: c++, size-t

The code tries to figure out if two strings have the same pattern.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>


bool findMatch(char * s1, char * s2){
    std::map<char, std::string> words;
    std::istringstream iss(s1);
    std::string word;
    //for (std::string::size_t i = 0; i < s2.size(); ++i)      //line 1
    //for (int i = 0; i < s2.size(); ++i)                      //line 2
    {
        if (!(iss >> word))
            return false; 
        std::string& mapping = words[s2[i]];
        if (mapping == "")
            mapping = word; 
        else if (mapping != word)
            return false; 
    }
    return !(iss >> word); 
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    bool b = findMatch("red blue blue red red yellow", "abbaac");
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Questions:**
I had two tries, line 1 and line 2, neither of them worked

> line 1, Error: class "..." has no member "size_t"
>
> line 2: Error: char * s2 Expression must have class type

Any ideas?

Comment: `s2` is a `char*`, so it doesn't have a `size()` member function. You can use `std::strlen()` to determine the length (will be O(n) in the length of the string though). Also, it's `std::string::size_type`, not `std::string::size_t`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're inconsistent a bit. You use `char*` and use `std::string`s as well, `std::string` has the benefit of having the `size` method that you are using in the for loop. `std::string` doesn't have `std::string::size_t`, it's either `size_t` or `std::string::size_type`.

I'd replace your `char*` parameters to `const std::string&`, that way it works as you intended.

Answer (score 3):

There are at least a few problems, `size_t` is not part of string and s2 is not `std::string` so you need to use something like `strlen`:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s2); ++i)
```

which means you need to include `cstring`

```
#include <cstring>
```

and for consistency sake it probably makes more sense to use `std::string` in place of `char *`.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing line 1 to

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s2); ++i)
```

Comment: Same Error: char * s2 Expression must have class type

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Doh! I missed that detail.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I *am* an online compiler...or at least I thought I was ;-( I'll have to remember to use one in the future.

Comment: @Code-Guru There is an old thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916000/online-c-compiler-and-evaluator/14652386#14652386 which AFAIK is complete, the isocpp link will probably be updated so good to keep that one around.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Thanks for the link. I've used ideone.com in the past. Nice to know about others as well.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour p.s. I fixed my answer. If you are one of the downvotes, I'd appreciate an undo ;-)